# Fetch or get null rows from second table which contains repeated id - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table which contains data as shown below

**TicketID**  **Devices**
TKT1001  DC1234
TKT1001  DC1224
TKT1001  DC1211
TKT1001  DC2234
TKT1001  DC1334

**TicketID** **Accounts**
TKT1001  Accnt1234
TKT1001  Accnt1254
TKT1001  Accnt1224

And i need result as shown below

**TicketID**  **Devices** **Accounts**
TKT1001  DC1234   Accnt1234
TKT1001  DC1224   Accnt1254
TKT1001  DC1211   Accnt1224
TKT1001  DC2234   null
TKT1001  DC1334   null

Please help me out...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bad idea. The order of the rows in the table should not matter. However, if you add a (e.g. `Position`) column to the Devices and Accounts table and make a composite key of `TicketID` and `Position`, you can left join on that key and get what you want.

Comment: Why do you want to combine DC1234 with Accnt1234? Why not with Accnt1254 or Accnt1224? Why don't you join DC2234 with any account record? Are you looking for a random pairer? Are there no rules why to combine two particular records? Is is just: pick a random device, join a random account, pick the next random device and so on? That doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: we cannot control DB structure.. so cant change the table definationons. :( just we are expected to work the way they are..

Comment: the suggested query from @Gordon worked well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more complicated than it first appears.  You need to add a `join` key to get a 1-1 join and not generate a cartesian product.  You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select d.*, a.accounts
from (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by ticketid order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from devices d
     ) d left join
     (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by ticketid order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from accounts a
     ) a
     on d.ticketid = a.ticketid and d.seqnum = a.seqnum;
```

Note that this puts an arbitrary row number on the rows, so the results may not be exactly what you have in your query.  If you have a column that specifies ordering, then you should use that.